# Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, github-actions

I am having this error when I am trying to use selenium via github actions. There is no problem with the local tests, probably I am not installing the chrome properly.

```
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
```

I checked the versions of the driver and the chrome they are compatible, both using version 103. I searched and I couldn't find the problem.

ci.yml file

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Install Google Chrome # Using shell script to install Google Chrome
        run: |
          chmod +x ./scripts/InstallChrome.sh
          ./scripts/InstallChrome.sh
      - name: Test with Maven
        run: mvn clean test
```

The test

```
import connect.Connect;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DummyTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();

        opt.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

        opt.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

        opt.addArguments("--headless");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.tr/");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/a[5]")).click();

    }
```

InstallChrome.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Dependencies

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
          <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm the chrome version being installed by setting with an `echo` in your `InstallChrome.sh` file?

Comment: It already says the version in the build logs. `google-chrome-stable is already the newest version (103.0.5060.114-1)`. 
Also I added this command to start the chrome and it actually starts succesfully.
`google-chrome --version
  export DISPLAY=:99
  chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub &
  sudo Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &`
I will add the dependencies I used to the question. My local chrome is also version 103 so it should be worked since I can run the test with the same dependencies.